# How do I repeat a capturing group?

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have an input string that looks something like this:

```
HLI6Ch60000Ch500C0Ch46400Ch30000Ch21888Ch10E79CS07LCU3Ch37880Ch27800Ch16480CS8CA00000000000000000000
```

Now I don't care about the part that follows the last letter `A`, it'll always be `A` and exactly 20 numbers that are of no use to me. I do, however, need the part before the last letter `A`, and ideally, I'd need it to be separated into two different captures, just like this:

```
1: HLI6Ch60000Ch500C0Ch46400Ch30000Ch21888Ch10E79CS07
2: LCU3Ch37880Ch27800Ch16480CS8C
```

The only way to identify these matches is that they end with characters `CS` followed by two hexadecimal characters. I thought that a regular expression like `(.+?CS.{2})+` (or `(.+?CS[[:xdigit:]]{2})+`) would do the job but when tried on [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com), it only captures the last group and gives the following warning:

***Note***: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Which I thought suggests that I should use regular expression like `((.+?CS.{2})+)` instead and I mean – sure, now I get two captures, but they look like this:

```
1: HLI6Ch60000Ch500C0Ch46400Ch30000Ch21888Ch10E79CS07LCU3Ch37880Ch27800Ch16480CS8C
2: LCU3Ch37880Ch27800Ch16480CS8C
```

Meaning the first one is… slightly longer than I'd like it to be. If it helps in any way, I should point out that the final regular expression will be part of an iOS application so an instance of `NSRegularExpression` class will be used – not sure if that's a helpful information at all, it's just that I know that `NSRegularExpression` doesn't support every part of the world of regular expressions.

Comment: Just use this one: `(.+?CS.{2})(.+?CS.{2})`, https://regex101.com/r/zD4cO2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
(.+?CS[[:xdigit:]]{2})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lR7zI1/1)

You don't need to put the regex inside another capturing group and make it to repeat one or more times. Just print the group index 1 to get your desired output.

Comment: Ah, damn, I'm so sorry, I forgot to mention that there might be more HLI6/LCU3 parts before the final `A.{20}` part, not always just two!

Comment: @Cellane you only says that it ends with `[:xdigit:]]{2}` two xdigit characters.

Comment: Oh right, I failed at reading, again ._. So yours is the same as vks' in that case, upvoted and thank you so much for your time! I can't believe I haven't tried this.

Comment: @Cellane note that i'm the first to post tgis regex. You wrongly accepted an answer which was posted **2 mins** after mine. So vks's answer is same as mine. Not my answer is same as vks's.

Comment: Oh! You're absolutely right, I failed not only at reading but also at noticing that. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

```
(.+?CS.{2})
```

You can direclty use this.See demo.Grab the group or capture.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/68

Comment: Whoa, thank you so much! I… can't believe I didn't think of that. So simple!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you need a capturing group at all:

```
(?:(?!CS[0-9A-F]{2}).)+CS[0-9A-F]{2}
```

will match all strings that end in CS + 2 hex digits.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dD6sS9/1).

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                # Start a group.
 (?!CS[0-9A-F]{2}) # Make sure we can't match CSff here,
 .                 # if so, match any character.
)+                 # Do this at least once.
CS[0-9A-F]{2}      # Then match CSff.
```

Comment: That feels almost like magic, amazing – thank you, that works as well. I might have to resort to using vks' solution though (although yours is probably faster to process, if I'm to guess?) due to its readability in case we need to make adjustments later. Still, thank you so much for your time!